# How to compute the time at which a predetermined number of events is reached for a given survival function using lifelines in Python?

Tags: python, survival, lifelines

Often clinical trial analyses are triggered based on reaching a predetermined number of events on an event-driven (time-to-event endpoint) study. This of course depends on the underlying survival function, the number of arms in the study, etc.

I reviewed the [`lifelines`](https://lifelines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Quickstart.html) documentation but did not find a simple way of computing the time at which a specific number of events is reached. How would I go about using current functionality in `lifelines`, or is there another library to consult here? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that there is a "simple" way to do this, in `lifelines` or any other survival software, if you want a detailed analysis. (Software-specific questions are off-topic here in any event.) But the approach is straightforward.

You presumably have a model that predicts survival as a function of time $t$, covariate values $X$, and treatment $A$, say $S(t|X,A)$. After a model is built, this model-specific prediction is provided in the software by a function with a name like `predict()`. To get a full analysis, construct a set of multiple hypothetical study participants $i$ with covariate values representing the covariate distributions among members of the population of interest. Predict the cumulative hazard (probability of an event up to time $t$) for each of those hypothetical participants, $F_i(t|X_i,A_i)= 1 - S(t|X_i,A_i)$, and average appropriately to represent the study population.
Multiplying that probability by the size of the study population gives you the number of events as a function of time.

In practice, particularly at early stages of evaluating study feasibility, a simple exponential survival curve might be assumed, with the rate parameter $\lambda$ determined by the known historical survival probability for the untreated population of interest at a particular point in time. That is, you assume a constant hazard, so the cumulative hazard over time has the simple form $F(t)=1-\exp(-\lambda t)$. Multiplying that probability by the initial untreated cohort size gives you the number of events in that cohort over time. Then take the treatment-associated change in $\lambda$ that you'd like to detect (hazard ratio) and repeat the calculation for the treated group. Together with appropriate handling of study entry and censoring over time, that's the basis of simple power estimates for survival studies, in which power is determined by the difference in the number of events between untreated and treated participants.